# jQuery rotating banner

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a jQuery rotating banner that I can use my own image thumbnails/layout for that I can just div tags instead of simple images.  I found this one: http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/lite/ but it's a bit outdated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just started using GalleryView from spaceforaname.com (http://spaceforaname.com/galleryview) and I like it a lot. It will allow you to use image or html content, automatic or manual transitions, and optional captioning.

Default/Basic example (you can turn off the caption overlay and just have the images or html content fill the space:

http://spaceforaname.com/gallery-light.html

Here is another example:

http://spaceforaname.com/webcomics.html

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you're wanting a [jQuery carousel](http://www.ajaxline.com/node/2220).  Luckily for you, there are lots of options out there!

Here's one that's not image-based:  [bxCarousel](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/bxcarousel)

Here's an example of how it works: [bxCarousel example](http://www.bxslider.com/)

Comment: I'm not really looking for a carousel, just a rotator/slider.

Comment: Sorry, I must not be up on the lingo... what's the difference?  Or, rather, aren't carousels just an implementation of a rotator/slider and thus can be used as rotators or sliders?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong.... I see a carousel as something where it's more 3D where you can see the other images behind it while seeing the main image.... I'm looking for something like this: http://www.starcraft-source.com/

Comment: Check out the bxCarousel link I provided in my answer - it doesn't work that way at all, and it seems really slick!

Answer (score 1):

You might try [Cycle2](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle2). This [demo](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle2/demo/non-image.php) page shows what you are looking for.